# Three span inside mat-option

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material2

I have a requirement to show mat-options like below

[image]

I have added three spans to cover them but they seems attached together.Here is the resulted image.[image]

Kindly help.

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let acc of fromAccounts.deposit" [value]="acc" >
                <span style="display: inline-block">{{acc.accountProductDesc}}</span>
                <span style="display: inline-block">{{acc.maskedAccountNumber}}</span>
                <span style="display: inline-block">{{acc.balance}}</span>
              </mat-option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to change the display of the `<mat-option>` content then fiddling with the scss should be all you need.

Of course CSS solutions are pretty much endless and there are a lot of ways to achieve what you want , you just have to pick what you think:

- is scalable (if needed)
- achieves what you want correctly
- is easy to understand/read/debug

Here's a simple approach I'd suggest:

#### Template:

```html
<mat-option *ngFor="let acc of fromAccounts.deposit" [value]="acc" >
  <div class="account-details">
    <span class="description">{{acc?.accountProductDesc}}</span>
    <span class="number">{{acc?.maskedAccountNumber}}</span>
    <span class="balance">{{acc?.balance | currency}}</span>
  </div>
</mat-option>
```

#### SCSS:

```css
.account-details{
  display: flex;
  *{
    padding: 0 3px;
  }
}
.description{
  font-weight: bold;
}
.number{
  font-size: small
}
.balance{
  margin-left: auto;
}
```