# Tags inside mat-option are removed

Tags: html, angular, mat-select

I put a `<span>` (or a `<div>`, or an `<em>`; I even tried an `<ng-container>` once) in the text inside  a `<mat-option>`, so that I could make some of the text a different color, like so:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="something">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let field of fields" [value]="field.name">
    <div class="tried-with-and-without">
      {{field.name}}
      <span class="or-em-or-div">
        ({{field.type}})
      </span>
    </div>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

When I inspect the resultant html in the browser, the innermost element comes out like this:

```
<span class="mat-select-min-line ng-tns-c156-9 ng-star-inserted">Name (text)</span>
```

You will note a distinct lack of any of the tags I had put in to format the text, which results in my formatting obviously not being applied. I have seen [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56488966/339772) that seem to indicate these tags should be surviving to the final result; what might I be doing wrong that is getting my tags removed?

Comment: Try to reproduce it on https://stackblitz.com. In advance, I'd say that the tags should be kept in the result.

Comment: What you are doing should work fine, see this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j5fdud?file=src/app/select-overview-example.html

Comment: Stackblitz is not behaving very well for me today (I think I might have internet connectivity issues or something), but I was finally able to get this working in there. I'm starting to wonder if something else on the page could be interfering. My first guess is having it inside a `<mat-list-item>`, but I don't know how long it will take until the internet will let me test it.

Comment: Ooooookay....... So I was finally able to copy my code to the StackBlitz. Everything worked fine. So I looked back at my original project, and all the sudden everything was working as expected. Absolutely no changes, it was just suddenly working. I don't think I even refreshed the page or anything. So yeah.... Color me baffled.

Comment: Wait, scratch that - it was working in the drop-down. The *selected* option was not showing any of this - because I had not made the changes there. So, yeah. ID10T error.